# How to run elastic search version 1.7.3 as a container on a Apple Mac OS M1 machine?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, apple-m1

I am trying to run Elastic search version 1.7.3(amd64 image) on my M1 machine but it exits immediately with an exception

```
org.testcontainers.containers.wait.internal.InternalCommandPortListeningCheck:call:47- An exception while executing the internal check: Container.ExecResult(exitCode=137, stdout=, stderr=/bin/sh: 1: nc: not found
/bin/bash: connect: Cannot assign requested address
```

Has anyone be able to build docker image for elastic search version 1.7.3 on M1 machine?

Comment: Have you tried via Brew? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/brew.html

Comment: @Justinas not version 7 but version 1.7 which is quite old

Comment: Don't you think that may be the issue? Mac m1 has different architecture from previous Macs. M1 uses Arm architecture. Also try adding `--platform linux/amd64` to your build process

Comment: It seems like there's a testcontainers layer involved here, which is expecting `nc` to be present somewhere; you're not just `docker run`ning the image?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Finally figured it out. Here's my Dockerfile. I am using tar file here

FROM ubuntu:bionic-20220531

## Must be root to install the packages

USER root
ENV discovery.type=single-node
ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS='-Des.script.disable_dynamic=false'

## Install required deps

RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install gnupg wget apt-transport-https coreutils java-common curl vim sudo tar

COPY elasticsearch-1.7.3.tar.gz /
RUN tar -xzf elasticsearch-1.7.3.tar.gz
RUN cd elasticsearch-1.7.3

## Install ARM Amazon JDK

RUN wget https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-8-aarch64-linux-jdk.deb -O amazon-jdk.deb
RUN dpkg --skip-same-version -i amazon-jdk.deb
RUN rm amazon-jdk.deb

WORKDIR /elasticsearch-1.7.3
ENTRYPOINT [ "./bin/elasticsearch" ]

Comment: Improve formatting. Use code formatting for Dockerfile